# Building SQL query between two number set

Tags: mysql, between

Hi i have a table **regd** like this

```
name | year | month
james| 2017 | 2
stacy| 2017 | 4
josh | 2017 | 8
june | 2017 | 9 
mary | 2018 | 1
hawk | 2018 | 2
sim  | 2018 | 3
```

How can I select all the people between month 8 of year 2017 to month 3 of year 2018.
Thank you for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Store dates as a single entity, e.g '2017-08-00'. If after that, you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Sorry but millions of that already stored in that table

Comment: No problem. Just fix it.

Comment: If you formulate your question (*people between ... and ...*) a little more verbose you basically have your SQL query. Hint: start out with a conditions for years 2017 and 2018 and then combine them. In any case the best solution is as Strawberry suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can write condition like below

```
year * 100 + month between 201708 and 201803

where 201708 = 2017 * 100 + 8 
and   201803 = 2018 * 100 + 3
```